# Get _id and display name of newly added contact : min API 7

Tags: android, contactscontract

In my application I am implementing functionality to add contact. For this purpose I am using code as

```
Intent addNewContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
addNewContact.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(addNewContact, ADD_NEW_CONTACT);
```

After adding contact (on Activity Result), I want to show that contact (only, and I don't want to iterate URI), *But I don't know how can I show only that contact. Is there a way?*

Here is my onActivityResult()

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == ADD_NEW_CONTACT) {
             if(resultCode == -1) {
                Log.i("New contact Added : ", "Addedd new contact, Need to refress item list");
            } else {
                Log.i("New contact Added : ", "Canceled to adding new contacts : Not need to update item list");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read [data](http://docs.mono-android.net/Android.App.Activity.OnActivityResult%20%28int,%20Android.App.Result,%20Android.Content.Intent%29)  parameter of `onActivityResult()`, in which you can get _id, displayName etc..

Try this code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == ADD_NEW_CONTACT) {
             if(resultCode == -1) {
                 Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        long newId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contacts._ID));
                        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        Log.i("New contact Added", "ID of newly added contact is : " + newId + " Name is : " + name);
                    }
                Log.i("New contact Added : ", "Addedd new contact, Need to refress item list : DATA = " + data.toString());
            } else {
                Log.i("New contact Added : ", "Canceled to adding new contacts : Not need to update database");
            }
        }
    }
```

Happy coding.

Comment: exactly the question i was in search of and exactly the answer i  needed! thanks!

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to do the same thing, but my data parameter is coming back null. I'm calling the insert contact action the same way as OP. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is OS version of your device? And check on another device too.